# How to change the font size in Android launcher?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I change the Font size in the android home Screen

The default HomeScreen is the Launcher Application in Android

I need to change the icon size and text size in the Grid View (I think AllAppsGridView is the class that defines the Grid View) I tried to change in the `launcher.xml` but it did not give me the result expected

Comment: Are you writing your own launcher? Or are you asking how to modify the design of another app (the launcher) from yours?